# Get Key, not value, of the ListPreference selection - Possible?

Tags: android, android-preferences

Getting the *value* of the currently selected item in a `ListPreference` is straightforward:

```
String selected = sharedPrefs.getString(
    getString(R.string.list_preference_array),
    "default string"
);
```

But now I need to get the **key** of the currently selected item, instead. Is this possible?

To clarify, a typical ListPreference definition in the XML file has the following components:

```
<ListPreference 
    android:key="@string/list_preference_array"
    android:title="Title of ENTIRE list (not seen by user?)"
    android:summary="this is what the user sees in small fonts" 
    android:defaultValue="just in case"
    android:entries="@array/user_friendly_labels" 
    android:entryValues="@array/code_meaningful_strings"
    android:dialogTitle="User Prompt(big font)" 
    android:showDefault="true"
    android:showSilent="true" 
/>
```

What `sharedPrefs.getString()` returns is the current selection from **android:entryValues**. What I am interested in getting is the current selection from **android:entries**. I mistakenly called it "key" but really it is a "corresponding label", which must be different than actual content.

Comment: isn't getString(R.string.select_string) the key of what you're getting?

Comment: @Erik `getString(R.string.select_string)` is the key ("name") of the entire ListPreference array, not the selection.

Comment: @uTubeFan, if you're using a ListPreference, there is no key for the selected item, only an entry...

Comment: @John Hmmm... What is the `android:entries=` for then? The returned string is the selection from `android:entryValues=` but I need to get the selected entry (I may have mistakenly called it "key" for lack of a better name).

Comment: `android:entries` is the text that the user will see when the list pops up, while `android:entryValues` is the value that will be returned to you after they click the entry.  You shouldn't need the `android:entries` value for anything in your code.  If you do need it, then you should set the `entries` and `entryValues` to be the same thing.

Comment: @John Ordinarily you are right of course, but in my particular case I need them different and I am interested to learn whether a trick that doesn't require array duplication exists. Thanks. :)

Comment: Why do you need the `android:entries` value? I guess you could search the `entryValues` array for the result and match the index to the value in the `entries` array, but I'm curious as to why you would need the `entries` value at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A bit of a guess:

```
int index = mylistpreference.findIndexOfValue(selected)  // <- selected taken from your code above
String entry = mylistpreference.getEntries()[index];
```

Answer (score 1):

just use:

```
mylistpreference.getEntry()
```

to get mylistpreference use:

```
mylistpreference= (ListPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(key);
```

key is the android:key you defined in preference.xml inside  < ListPreference> tag.

Answer (score 0):

The function is [defined](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) as

```
SharedPreferences.getString(String key, String defaultValue);
```

So in your example code, `getString(R.string.select_string)` would return the key.

When you add the `SharedPreference`, you need to specify the key, so the key would be the same one you used to set the value.

**Edit:**

using `SharedPreferences.getString()` with the ListPreference key as the key will return the value the user selected from the list.  You don't need to create keys for each option in the ListPreference array, and these keys aren't created automatically.  Use case statements that correlate to the ListPreference's `entryValues`.

Comment: See my reply to @Erik's comment.

Answer (score 0):

@shai Your method lags to last selected entry

```
listPreference.getEntry()
```

Rather @Erik 's method works nicely

```
int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue((String) value)
String entry = listpreference.getEntries()[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

**To properly update the summary of a ListPreference (using the label, instead of the key).**

```
   @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
            if (prefIndex >= 0) {
                CharSequence[] labels = listPreference.getEntries();
                preference.setSummary(labels[prefIndex]);
            }
        } else {
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }
        return true;

    }
```