# Get current ListPreference label from MainActivity

Tags: android, settings, listpreference

As explained here:
[Get Key, not value, of the ListPreference selection - Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261141/get-key-not-value-of-the-listpreference-selection-possible)
and many other places, it is quite easy to access ListPreferences labels from PreferenceActivity.

What I need to do is to read the label corresponding to the current selected from the **main activity**.
But I can't find a way.

For example, in my main activity I have

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

I would like to use something like:

```
ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) settings.findPreference("list_of_countries");
```

And then handle it to get current value and label.

### Update 01

I tried to handle another way to retrieve the summary (the name of a country in my example) value which I need to say the customer what he selected. I can't give him the code!

```
private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();
        String stringSummary = preference.getSummary().toString();
        String stringKey = preference.getKey().toString();
        if (stringKey.equals("list_of_countries")){
            MyActivity.countryName = stringSummary;
        }
```

Nothing to do... the OnPreferenceChangeListener is called.... BEFORE the preference change, i.e., when one item is clicked, so what I succeed to retrieve is just the past summary.
I found no way.

Comment: what you get  `listPreference`  ?

Comment: Nothing, I can't call it inside the main activity.

Comment: any error you getting ?

Comment: SweetWisher, I '''CAN'T''' get the ListPreference from the MainActivity.

Comment: I am not getting you why you cant *You **CAN'T** get the ListPreference from the MainActivity*

Comment: For example because a `SharedPreferences` instance like `settings` has no `findPreferences(...)` method.